# Android get UTC milliseconds from GMT milliseconds

Tags: java, android, date, utc, gmt

I have a time variable in GMT and I will convert in UTC. I post my code:

```
long mytime = 1376824500000;
Date date = new Date(mytime);
String time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(date);
```

This return `"13:15"` in some device, but I would like to have always UTC date: `"11:15"`.
How can I do that?

Comment: Set the timezone to GMT.  BTW Like most languages, Java doesn't support leap seconds so UTC is actually mapped to GMT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear what difference you're expecting between UTC and GMT - for the purposes we're talking here, they're equivalent. (They're not quite technically the same, but...)

In terms of *formatting*, you just need to set the time zone on your formatter:

```
// TODO: Consider setting a locale explicitly
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
String time = format.format(date);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I haven't set the time zone. In some devices I get the GMT+2.00 formatted value, in other I get the utc value. Thanks.

Comment: @Tenaciousd93: Yes, you haven't set the time zone, so you're getting the local time zone. If you want the UTC time zone, you need to be explicit about that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
long mytime = 1376824500000;
Date date = new Date(mytime);
SimpleDateFormat formater = = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
formater .setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
String time formater.format(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.OffsetTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(1_376_824_500_000L);
        OffsetDateTime odtUtc = instant.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        LocalTime time = odtUtc.toLocalTime();
        System.out.println(time);

        // If you want the time with timezone offset
        OffsetTime ot = odtUtc.toOffsetTime();
        System.out.println(ot);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
11:15
11:15Z
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/j7fVOw)

The `Z` in the output is the [timezone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) for zero-timezone offset. It stands for Zulu and specifies the `Etc/UTC` timezone (which has the timezone offset of `+00:00` hours).

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>